# Getting taxonomy category Image from ACF

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I'm really new to php and I'm trying to get an image set using advanced custom fields on my front end. I've looked at the docs and forums but I can't get the url. All the code works but for the image. I expect the url value to show up but instead I get a blank value. I know I need to get the taxonomy ID, I must be missing something.

Here is an image of my ACF settings: https://puu.sh/xFI3Y/23bea86ecf.png

And it's rules: https://puu.sh/xFI5N/2865cecc5a.png

```
<?php  
  // get all the categories from the database  
  $cats = get_categories();  

  // loop through the categories  
  foreach ($cats as $cat) {  
    // setup the category ID  
    $cat_id= $cat->term_id;  
  ?>  
<div style="background: url( <?php the_field('category-image', 'term_'. $cat_id); ?> );"></div>   
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using version 5.5.0 or newer since only that version support the format

```
'term_' . $id
```

Try passing `$cat` as the second parameter to `the_field()`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this code:

```
$cat_image = get_field('category_image', $cat);
echo "<div class='catalog-category'>
<h2 class='category-title'>".$cat->name."</h2>";?>  
<div class="category-image" style="background: url( <?= $cat_image ?> );</div>
```

Thanks for the help! Sorry for the noob question.